# Converting SQL to relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Does anyone know any good online resources which I can use to practise SQL to relational algebra conversion?

Comment: SQL is the most common way to express [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) on a computer.  What kind of language would you convert it to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL -> Relational Algebra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771490/sql-relational-algebra)

Comment: I just want to be able to express an SQL statement as in its relational algebraic form (using selection, projection, intersection, union etc)

Comment: @Andomar, not a duplicate of that question. This ask a general question, the other an example SQL statement for a given query.

Answer (score 9):

See: http://db.grussell.org/index.html
The following powerpoint presentation may also be of help:
http://www.cs.wayne.edu/~shiyong/csc6710/slides/kiferComp_348761_ppt05.ppt

Comment: Half answers the question. +1 nonetheless for good sources. The sources don't explain how to convert aggregate SQL operators (like GROUP BY) to RA, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

The online tool [RelaX](http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/) will allow you to convert SQL to Relational Algebra.  You can also compose and execute relational algebraic expressions on small datasets.